# How to retrieve the current system design from a UIFont instance?

Tags: ios, uifont, uifontdescriptor

Given a `UIFont` instance, how can I determine what system design it is using? This is the value `UIFontDescriptor.SystemDesign` which can be one of: `default`, `monospaced`, `rounded` or `serif`.

I see how to set this via `UIFontDescriptor.withDesign()` but it's not clear how to read that value on the current font.

Comment: Have you checked to fontDescriptor of the UIFont? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/1619037-fontdescriptor

Comment: I would also like to retrieve the font weight aka `UIFont.Weight`. If the solution points the same direction as getting the design I'll combine it into my question. (There is already a question for getting weight https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331388/get-font-weight-of-an-uitextview but does not provide a satisfactory solution.)

Comment: The `fontDescriptor` returns a `UIFontDescriptor` object which has SystemDesign?

Comment: From what I can see the font descriptor attributes does not have system design. Possibly it's buried in `UIFontDescriptor.fontAttributes`, but I don't see anything obvious.

Comment: Any success on this one?